# CSS, HTML div height

Tags: html, css, height

Each 2 div is of different size and they must be the same height.

CSS:

```
.bbb {
    width: 333px;
    height: 2px;
    max-height: 2px;
    background: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bbb"></div><br><br>
<div class="bbb"></div><br><br>
<div class="bbb"></div><br><br>
<div class="bbb"></div><br><br>
<div class="bbb"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dgujw5k/)
and
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqpYF.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this can actually be fixed on all browsers, at all zoom levels,. or not Your problem arises because the system is having to map the several screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel and sometimes a screen pixel gets 'left behind' in the calcualtions (a bit like a rounding error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative way. It is working for me now

```css
.bbb {
    width: 333px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on the CodePen, it was working fine. However your JSFiddle was also working fine and each of the lines are having the same margin.

Try using a different browser to view your html page and let me know.

Try this code, and let me know how is it working in your system.

```css
.bbb {
    width: 333px;
    height: 2px;
    max-height: 2px;
    background: black;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.bbb:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
```

Kindly keep me informed about the new issue you are facing right now.

Note - Kindly change the values of margin in class .bbb and also of the margin-top in the .bbb:nth-child(1) according to your convinience.

And sometimes different browsers show a file in different style maybe because of different factors like zoom level etc. Install some other browser like Mozilla Firefox Developer version / Chrome

Comment: What browser are you using? Try it at different zoom levels.

Comment: I'm using the Chrome browser

Comment: Try different browser like Firefox @FuF

Answer (score -1):

you can use a :nth-child to change size of div for example width and height of the tag